# Ruby on rails - using submit to get different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a little problem. I'm doing a little project and I'm stuck on something fairly simple, but can't get past throug it. I've a form, and after submiting it, it redirects me to view 'show', but I've wanted to change that it would redirected me to 'show15'. I'm preety new with rails, so it may be a little stupdi question, but would really apreciate help. Thanks in advance.

That's my form:

```
<%= form_for(@patient)  do |f| %> 
  <% if @patient.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@patient.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this patient from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @patient.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :imie %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :imie %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :nazwisko %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :nazwisko %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :adres %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :adres %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pesel %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :pesel %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :telefon %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :telefon %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :doktor %><br />
    <%= collection_select(:imie, :imie, Doctor.all, :id, :full_name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Edytuj", class: "show15", value: 'Edytuj' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your *form will take you to the **create action*** inside your patients controller. You simply need to **redirect it to your custom action** inside your create action when your patient is saved inside database.

```
def create
  @patient = Patient.new patient_params
  if @patient.save
    redirect_to your_path_of_show15
  else
    render new
  end
end
```

I'm assuming inside your create action you would have something like *redirect_to @patient by which rails takes you to the show action of newly created patient.* For more information on how routes work in rails refer to [rail guides routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `patients_controller` (I am guessing the name, based on the name of your `@patient` variable), you probably have something that looks like this:

```
  def create    
    @patient = Patient.new(patients_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @patient.save
        format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @patient, status: :created, location: @patient }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Rails uses a [RESTful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) approach. This line specifically:

```
format.html { redirect_to @patient, notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
```

is what is causing the `show` page to load "automatically". You can alter this behaviour a couple of ways. One method is simply inserting the url directly in the method call, like so:

```
format.html { redirect_to "patients/show15" ... }
```

Or, depending on how you set up your `routes.rb`, if you did something like this:

```
resources :patients do
    collection do
        get :show15
        ...
    end
end
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
format.html { redirect_to show15_patients_path ... }
```